# Unexpected FeignException instead of ResponseEntity when the server returns 401

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

In our application we use `spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:4.1.0` for some interservice communication. Here's one of our clients:

```java
@FeignClient(name = "authClient", url = "${spring.microservice.tenant-auth.host}")
public interface AuthClient {
    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> getAuthToken(AuthFormData formData);
}

public class AuthFormData {

    private String grant_type;
    private String client_id;
    private String client_secret;

    public void setGrantType(String grantType) {
        this.grant_type = grantType;
    }

    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.client_id = clientId;
    }

    public void setClientSecret(String clientSecret) {
        this.client_secret = clientSecret;
    }
}

public class AuthenticationResponse {

    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    private String accessToken;
    @JsonProperty("token_type")
    private String tokenType;
    @JsonProperty("expires_in")
    private int expiresIn;
    @JsonProperty("scope")
    private String scope;
    @JsonProperty("refresh_token")
    private String refreshToken;
    @JsonProperty("id_token")
    private String idToken;
}
```

In general this code works fine, but what puzzles me is the `FeignException` thrown from the callee in case the server returns 401:

```java
AuthenticationResponse getToken(AuthFormData authFormData) {
    var authResponse = authClient.getAuthToken(authFormData);
    var body = authResponse.getBody();
    if (!authResponse.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful() || body == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to get auth token " + authResponse);
    }
    return body;
}
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
feign.FeignException$Unauthorized: [401 Unauthorized] during [POST] to [https://somethin.com/oauth/token] [AuthClient#getAuthToken(AuthFormData)]: []
    at feign.FeignException.clientErrorStatus(FeignException.java:224) ~[feign-core-13.1.jar:na]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:203) ~[feign-core-13.1.jar:na]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:194) ~[feign-core-13.1.jar:na]
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:103) ~[feign-core-13.1.jar:na]
    at feign.InvocationContext.decodeError(InvocationContext.java:126) ~[feign-core-13.1.jar:na]
    at feign.InvocationContext.proceed(InvocationContext.java:72) ~[feign-core-13.1.jar:na]
    at feign.ResponseHandler.handleResponse(ResponseHandler.java:63) ~[feign-core-13.1.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:114) ~[feign-core-13.1.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:70) ~[feign-core-13.1.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:99) ~[feign-core-13.1.jar:na]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy113.getAuthToken(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at c.c.o.p.m.AuthenticationTokenProvider.getToken(AuthenticationTokenProvider.java:34) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

If the response is 200 or 500 then the `ResponseEntity` with corresponding status code is returned.

So my question is why do I get exception for 401 and is there a way to make the `AuthClient` return `ResponseEntity` with 401?